# Why is it interesting to study gravity in (2+1)D?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime-dimensions

I often see people researching (2+1)-Gravitational theories such as Chern-Simons. Why is it interesting or what's the motivation underlying that study if there are 4 macroscopic dimensions?

Comment: Minor suggestion: you might change the title from '3D' to '(2+1) d' or 'two spatial dimensions,' etc, so it is less ambiguous.

Comment: Simpler mathematics , as with quantum mechanics one dimensional potentials http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/Quantum/node45.html

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99521